# Databinding to PropertyValueCollection of a Directory Entry in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to bind a `ListView` column to a property value of a `DirectoryEntry`'s Properties Collection in C# WPF

However I cannot seem to get the right syntax to access the following for one of my columns binding:

```
Properties["Department"].Value
```

Sample code below:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace TestWPF
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 private void SetupColumns()
    {
        var gridView = new GridView();
        this.listView.View = gridView;
        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
                {
                    Header = "Name",
                    DisplayMemberBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Name")
                });
        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
        {
            Header = "Department",
            DisplayMemberBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Properties[\"Department\"].Value") //NEEDS TO GET Properties["Department"].Value for the binding
        });
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        SetupColumns();
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry();
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry)
        {
            PageSize = int.MaxValue, 
            Filter = "name=jbloggs"
        };
        List<DirectoryEntry> d1 = new List<DirectoryEntry>();
        foreach (SearchResult t in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            d1.Add(t.GetDirectoryEntry());

        }
        DataContext = d1;
        listView.ItemsSource = d1;
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the escaped quotes from the binding path:

```
DisplayMemberBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Properties[Department].Value")
```